clerk createdSessionId is an empty string when using google auth in an expo app
I'm trying to use Google AUTH using Clerk, When clicking on the button the Google sign in page successfully opens, and I can choose an account to sign in with, but on the redirect the createdSessionId is an empty string and the user is null.
import { Colors } from "@/constants/Colors";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Icon } from "../shared/icon";
import { OAuthStrategy } from "@clerk/types";
import { useOAuth } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";

interface AuthBtnProps {
  isOAuthLoading: boolean;
  setIsOAuthLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  buttonIcon: string;
  strategy: OAuthStrategy;
}

export const AuthBtn: React.FC<AuthBtnProps> = ({
  isOAuthLoading,
  setIsOAuthLoading,
  buttonIcon,
  strategy,
}) => {
  const { startOAuthFlow } = useOAuth({ strategy });

  const handleOAuth = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setIsOAuthLoading(true);
      const { createdSessionId, setActive } = await startOAuthFlow({
        redirectUrl: Linking.createURL("/home"),
      });

      console.log({ createdSessionId });

      if (createdSessionId) {
        setActive!({ session: createdSessionId });
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      Toast.show({
        type: "error",
        text1: "Error",
        text2: error.errors[0].message,
      });
    } finally {
      setIsOAuthLoading(false);
    }
  }, [setIsOAuthLoading, startOAuthFlow]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.8}
      style={[
        styles.button,
        isOAuthLoading && { backgroundColor: Colors.gray },
      ]}
      disabled={isOAuthLoading}
      onPress={handleOAuth}
    >
      <Icon name={buttonIcon} color={Colors.white} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 14,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: 10,
  },
});

I tried signing in with Discord and GitHub and they worked fine
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import { AuthBtn } from "./auth-btn";

export const useWarmUpBrowser = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    void WebBrowser.warmUpAsync();
    return () => {
      void WebBrowser.coolDownAsync();
    };
  }, []);
};

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export const Social: React.FC = () => {
  useWarmUpBrowser();
  const [isOAuthLoading, setIsOAuthLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AuthBtn
        strategy="oauth_google"
        buttonIcon="google"
        isOAuthLoading={isOAuthLoading}
        setIsOAuthLoading={setIsOAuthLoading}
      />
      <AuthBtn
        strategy="oauth_discord"
        buttonIcon="discord"
        isOAuthLoading={isOAuthLoading}
        setIsOAuthLoading={setIsOAuthLoading}
      />

      <AuthBtn
        strategy="oauth_github"
        buttonIcon="github"
        isOAuthLoading={isOAuthLoading}
        setIsOAuthLoading={setIsOAuthLoading}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    gap: 10,
  },
});

